# Inside a C# if can I the first test stop other tests or do all tests get executed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
@if (@Model.Meta.LinkKey.IsNotNullOrEmptyOrZeros() & !@Model.Meta.LinkKey.EndsWith("-"))
```

It's ASP.NET MVC so I can only use **one if()** and everything has to fit inside that. The first test works okay if the value is null but then the next test fails with a message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is there a way that I can make C# not do any more testing if the first condition shows that the value is a null? I seem to recall this was possible in C but I am not sure how to do it in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use `&` and not `&&` you don't short circuit the evaluation of the second Boolean expression. In it's current form it evaluates both expressions then determines whether they we're both true.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` instead of `&` to enable short-circuiting operations. `&` is a binary and.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `&&` -- as it is the code isn't going what you think! `&` is the *bitwise AND* operator, and is certainly not what you want.

`&&` is boolean AND, and also shortcuts on failure.